# Rake aborted (db:seed) - "Can't Convert Symbol to Integer" error

Tags: integer, rake, nested-attributes, symbols

I've researched just about every post on StackOverflow with "Can't Convert Symbol to Integer" in the title, but still haven't been able to figure out why I'm getting this error when I try to run the **rake db:seed** command.

Here's the trace for the rake command:

```
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
can't convert Symbol into Integer
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:397:in `[]'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:397:in `block in assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:397:in `map'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:397:in `assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:289:in `sponsors_attributes='
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:94:in `block in assign_attributes'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:93:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:93:in `assign_attributes'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/validations.rb:39:in `new'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/validations.rb:39:in `create!'
C:/Sites/giggo/db/seeds.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:520:in `load_seed'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:347:in `block (2 levels) in <top(required)>'

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

Here's the code in my **seeds.rb** file:

```
User.delete_all

params = { :user => 
    { :password => '123abc',
      :password_confirmation => '123abc',
      :uname => 'sponsorABC',
      :user_type => 'sponsor',
      :artists_attributes => {},
      :sponsors_attributes =>
        { :address => '1000 Wilshire, Los Angeles, CA',
          :email => 'abc@abc.com',
          :name => 'sponsorABC',
          :phone => '310-555-8000'
        }
      }
}

User.create!(params[:user])
```

(the last line is line 27 in the file). And here's the code included in the `create` action for my Users controller:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @artist = @user.artists.build(params[:user]) if params[:user][:artists_attributes]
    @sponsor = @user.sponsors.build(params[:user]) if params[:user][:sponsors_attributes]

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_url(@user), notice: 'User #{@user.uname} was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

It appears the nested attributes in the hash I created in my **seeds.rb** file are creating the error, but can't figure out how to resolve the issue. Is this error being generated because of the way I've defined the hash? Or is this a problem with the way I'm creating the instance variables in the controller? All suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!